# Induction proof for Tchebyshev polynomials

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, induction

It is known that $\cos nx$ can be expressed as $n$-th degree polynomial in powers of $\cos x$ (that is actually Tchebyshev polynomial $T_n(x)$). Can this be shown using induction only?

Comment: You can use the Fourier transform with the convolution theorem to prove it smoothly.

Comment: Use $\cos(n+1)x+\cos(n-1)x=2\cos x\cos nx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Indeed $\cos ((n+1)x) = -\cos((n-1)x) + 2\cos(x)\cos(nx)$. Then it is enough to take the sequence of polynomials such that $T_{n+1}(x) = -T_{n-1}(x) + 2 x T_n(x)$. For the initialization $T_0(x) = 1$ and $T_1(x) = x$ satisfy the condition for $n=0$ and $n=1$